# How get a course section details in Canvas LTI 2.0

Tags: canvas, canvas-lms, lti, ims

I want to fetch the course section details from Canvas, I am using LTI 2.0.
Asper the API document I can get the section sis_id's that the user is enrolled in but I am not getting this.

https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.tools_variable_substitutions.html

```
enabled_capability: %w(
              basic-lti-launch-request
              User.id
              Canvas.api.domain
              LtiLink.custom.url
              User.username
              Person.email.primary
              Person.name.full
              CourseSection.sourcedId
              Canvas.course.sectionIds
              Person.sourcedId
              Membership.role
              ToolConsumerProfile.url)
          }
```

Note: I have added the section to a course and also assigned SIS ids it.

I am unable to find any section related info, how can I get section info in which a user is enrolled?

Thanks

Comment: how are you adding the LTI to the course? Did you use an XML config file?

Comment: LTI 2.0 is using URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search, I am moving back to LTI 1.0 as this and many other features are not supported in LTI.2

Comment: What about LTI 1.3? That's the recommended version, right?